# $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) doesn't work properly in SPA Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a AngularJs beginner and I want to create a simple and basic SPA according to **[single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)** from **https://scotch.io/**.

before using `$locationProvider` all things worked fine, means by click any link, related Pages calls and shown in main template:

This is my `index.html` page as main Page :

```
    <div class="container" style="width: 960px;" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Main</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">

            <div id="main">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And This is my Angular Codes includes routes and other configurations :

```
    var mySPA = angular.module('SPA', ['ngRoute']);

mySPA.config(['$routeProvider' , '$locationProvider' ,function ($routeProvider , $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/contact.php',
            controller: 'contactController'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

mySPA.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message  =   'I am a Message in Home Page';
}])
.controller('aboutController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message  =   'Here is About Us page';
}])
.controller('contactController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message  =   'Here is Contact Us page';
}]);
```

My `index.html` page is in `Angular.dev/SPA` Directory on my local server and my Server Configuration is same as described on [this Page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Angular.dev

    DocumentRoot 'D:\wamp\www\Angular'

    <Directory D:\wamp\www\Angular>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 

state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I added `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to end of `.config()` method and after all Routes definitions , my App did not work Properly .

Also I added `base` tag in head element like this :

```
<base href="/SPA/index.html">
```

But by click on links , no things happens.

Of course when I copy for example `http://angular.dev/SPA/index.html#about` url into separate browser tab , redirects to `http://angular.dev/SPA/about` and show desired page But again other links doesn't work and doesn't open without reload.

what is problem and how can solve that ?

Comment: all the href tag should have `\` a start like `href="/contact"`

Comment: @PankajParkar, I try that but when I click `http://angular.dev/SPA/index.html#/about` link address bar change to `http://angular.dev/SPA/index.html#%2Fcontact` and nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by create a htaccess file in route server directory by this content :

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ SPA/index.html [L]
```

And I change Links like this(I remove # from begin of those) :

```
<div class="container" style="width: 960px;" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li>
                    <a href="./">Main</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">

            <div id="main">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Also in the `head` changed `base` tag to :

```
<base href="/SPA/">
```

And my SPA works fine.

Comment: You could try without base: `$locationProvider.html5Mode({'enabled': true, 'requireBase': false})` See: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase